# Java - Check for TCP Port availability

Tags: java, eclipse, tcp, eclipse-plugin, serversocket

I am checking for availability of a TCP port like this:

```
public static boolean isTCPPortAvailable(int hostPort) {
    ServerSocket tempSocket = null;
    try {
        tempSocket = new ServerSocket();
        // Enable Reuse before binding
        tempSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        tempSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(hostPort));
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // Denotes that port is in use
    }
    finally {
        if(tempSocket != null) {
            try {
                tempSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // Not to be thrown
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that this method is returning true even if port is in `LISTENING` state. Can anybody help me find the issue.

NOTE: I am using `setReuseAddress(true)` to ignore `TIME_WAIT` state.

NOTE: I am on Windows.

Comment: Down voters can you please comment you reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of this. Just use port zero. The system will give you the next available port.

NB an `IOException` does *not* 'denote that the port is in use'. Only *some* `BindExceptions` do that.

Comment: No i have to take port numbers as an input. I can't use any other port number.

Comment: I'm surprised that a person with your reputation should write a comment as an answer. And how do you know what the OP needs? Perhaps his program has a property set by the user for the port, and it wants to make sure that the user-requested port is available?

Comment: @ShoaibShakeel For what reason? Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm surprised that a person with any reputation at all would construe an answer as a comment.

Comment: I am enhancing eclipse debugger and using QEMU for emulation. I need specific ports to pass to QEMU for redirection.

Comment: @ShoaibShakeel Your development environment is really of no interest whatsoever. Either you need a dynamic port at runtime, in which case port zero is exactly what you are looking for, or you have misconstrued your problem, or your problem has been incorrectly specified. Which is it?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my lsat comment. What i described was not my dev env. But Eclipse based application. I am writing plugins for Eclipse. And I need to enhance debugger. User specifies which port to use.

Comment: So you don't need to check for TCP port availability. You need to attempt to create the application on the socket specified, and deal with the consequences if it isn't available. Trying to predict the future as you are now is simply fallacious. For example the port could be available when you test but unavailable when you bind. Or vice versa. The correct way to test the availability of *any* resource is simply to try to use it in the normal course of events and deal with the failures as they actually arise.